# Какие есть варианты управления игрой (3 в ряд) в консоли?

Tags: c++, cmd, консоль

Сейчас используется метод координат, что дико неудобно, но других вариантов управления я не придумал.

```
        while (nice == false) {
            cin >> f >> s;
            if ((f and s > 11) or (f and s < 99)) {
                if ((f / 10) - (s / 10) == 1 or -1) {
                    if ((f % 10) - (s % 10) == 1 or -1) { nice = true; } //Ввод и проверка 
                }
            }
        }
        game[f / 10][f % 10] = game[s / 10][s % 10];

    Загаловочные файлы #include "stdafx.h" #include <iostream> #include <stdlib.h> #include <time.h>
```

Comment: заголовочные файлы какие используете?

Comment: и что за игра вообще?

Comment: Могли бы Вы убрать весь несущественный код и оставить только то, что имеет отношение к вопросу. Кроме того, опишите Вашу игру словесно. В таком случае не придётся разбираться с тем, что написали и ответ Вами будет получен быстрее.

Comment: 3 в ряд, только для консоли. Внес правки в вопрос

Comment: Еще желателно описать назначение переменных и смысл всех магических целочисленных литералов

Comment: @acade описание может не понадобиться, если давать переменным осмысленные (значащие) имена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще если хотите написать консольное приложение (игру) в котором вам нужно взаимодействовать с элементами на экране, то вам нужен `curses` (под `windows` есть `pdcurses`). Вот пример что можно сделать с его помощью: [консольный тэтрис для винды](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1k2Npvwtn8TOfFMw1Jq6YlJSaGtK5klAG?usp=sharing) и [ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/tetris.git), а также ближе к вашей игре [судоку](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxM92zv79qxrWFFxYzNCNjFpRjA) и [ссылка ни гитхаб](https://github.com/andrejlevkovitch/sudoku.git).

PS: у вас ошибка в цикле `while`

```
while (q = true) {
```

Ваше `=` это присваивание, а не условие.